# problem help me gas * price + value

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I've seen many topics, but I've yet not solved my problem. Please, help me!

```
 var EthereumTx=require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
 const Web3=require('web3')
 const web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/85xxxxxxxxxxx2af25e829b8d9df')
 const account1='0xbd77caf08fe49d3f5aef6f83fc23b8d2129b468f'
 const main = async () => {
    const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf5aef6f83fc23b8d2129b468f');
    const nonce = web3.utils.toHex(count);
    const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');

  const gasLimit = web3.utils.toHex(3000000)
  const gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(22 * 1e9) // 5 gwei
 const privateKey = Buffer.from(
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'hex',
)

        const txParams = {
          from: "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9b468f",
          gasPrice: gasPrice,
          gasLimit: gasLimit,
          to: '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb91a04e',
          value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1','ether')),
          data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
         chainId: '0x03'

        }
// The second parameter is not necessary if these values are used
const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams, { chain: 'rinkeby', hardfork: 'petersburg' })
tx.sign(privateKey)
const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
    const raw ='0x'+serializedTx.toString('hex')
    // broadcast the trasnaction 

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,(err,txHash)=>{
      console.log('err:',err,'txHash:',txHash)
    })
 }

main();
```

I've got this error

> Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Comment: For Rinkeby chainId is 4, not 3. Check private key is valid, after signing [`tx.getSenderAddress()`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/blob/master/packages/tx/docs/classes/_transaction_.transaction.md#getsenderaddress) should return the same as from if correct.

Comment: change chainId to 4 ,
chek private key is true ,
and after signing private key enter tx.getSenderAddress()
but is not working and yet error insufficient funds for gas * price + value please help me :(

Comment: Please share everything except for your Infura project ID and your private key (i.e., the value of the `from` field, the value of the `to` field, and the account address which you pass to `getTransactionCount` (which should be the same as the value of the `from` field)).

Comment: Do you have at least 1.066 ether in the account whose private key is `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`?

Comment: If your account is the same used in the example then it has zero balance in rinkeby.